# NextJS + MongoDB : Forum app, getTopicsByCategories

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js

I'm new to NextJS (14.1.3) and want to develop a discussion forum application.
I've implemented 2 schemas like this :

```js
// Import Mongoose and Schema from mongoose package
import mongoose, { Schema } from "mongoose";

// Connect to MongoDB using the provided URI in the environment variable MONGODB_URI
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);

// Set Mongoose promises to use the global Promise object
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

// Define a schema for the Category model
const categorySchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: String,
        description: String
    },
)

// Define the Category model using the schema
// If the model already exists, use it; otherwise, create a new one
const Category = mongoose.models.Category || mongoose.model("Category", categorySchema);

// Export the Category model for use in other files
export default Category;
```

```js
import mongoose, { Schema } from "mongoose";

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const topicSchema = new Schema(
    {
        title: String,
        categoryId: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Category",
        },
    },
)

const Topic = mongoose.models.Topic || mongoose.model("Topic", topicSchema);

export default Topic;
```

I have 2 components: Category.jsx and CategoryPage.jsx

```js
import Link from 'next/link'
import React from 'react'

const Category = ({ category }) => {
  return (
    <Link href={'/'}>
      <div className='border-2 border-gray-200 shadow-lg rounded-md p-5'>
        { category.name }
      </div>
    </Link>
  )
}

export default Category
```

```js
import Category from './Category'
const CategoryPage = ({ categories }) => {

  return (
      <div>
        <ul className='flex flex-col gap-3'>
            {categories.map((category, _index) => (
                <li key={_index}>
                    <Category
                        category={category}
                    />
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CategoryPage
```

In app/api/Categories, i have a route.js

```js
// Import the Category model from "@/app/models/Category"
import Category from "@/app/models/Category";

// Import NextResponse from "next/server"
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

// Define a GET function to handle HTTP GET requests
export async function GET() {
    try {
        // Fetch all categories from the database and sort them by name in ascending order
        const categories = (await Category.find().sort({ name: 1 }));

        // Return a JSON response with the fetched categories and a status of 200 OK
        return NextResponse.json({ categories }, { status: 200});
    } catch (error) {
        // If an error occurs during the fetching process, return a JSON response with an error message and status of 500 Internal Server Error
        return NextResponse.json({message: "Error", error}, { status: 500});
    }
}
```

In page.js (root folder) :

```js
import CategoryPage from "./components/CategoryPage";

export const getCategories = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/Categories", {
      cache: "no-store"
    });

    return res.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Failed to get categories", error);
  }
};

export default async function Home() {

  const { categories } = await getCategories();

  return (
    <section className="p-5 xl:p-10">
      <h1 className="text-3xl mb-5">Categories list</h1>
      <CategoryPage 
        categories={categories}
      />
    </section>
  );
}
```

So far, I've managed to display the list of forum categories when i click on a category in my Category Component (Link is already here)
I'd like to know how to link to the topics to display the list of topics by category.